# “UPDATE WHEN DUPLICATE ELSE INSERT” when key is not PRIMARY KEY in MySql

Tags: mysql

How to do `"on duplicate key update"` when the key is not `primary`.

*Example:*

```
INSERT INTO customers (`id`,`user_id`, `status`, `category_id`, `date`)
VALUES  ('1','123','test','12','2018-09-08') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
id=VALUES(id),
status=values(status),
date=values(date);
```

I want to update the table if both `user_id` and `category` matches else insert a new row.

Comment: Create Unique index for user_id and category

Comment: I tried it, doesn't seem to work.

Comment: In what way didn't it work? How did you create the index? Please add that detail to your question using the `edit` button under the tags.

Comment: "Didn't work", it produced and error? No data changed? It crashed the server? Nothing changed? It started a small black hole that you managed to contain? :-) Please be specific.

Comment: Can you show 'SHOW CREATE TABLE customers' in the question in answer to Nick's question.

Comment: @danblack unique index actually worked. Thank you

Comment: glad to hear it. Happy SQLing.

Answer (score 0):

As per comments the unique index was missing:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX user_category ON customers (user_id, category_id)
```